# pass html content as a variable to html2canvas for pdf generation

Tags: javascript, html2canvas

```
var doc = document.getElementById('name').innerHTML;

html2canvas(doc, {
                useCORS: true,
                allowTaint: true,
                onrendered: function(canvas) {         
                    var imgData = canvas.toDataURL(
                        'image/png');              
                    var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm');
                    doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 10, 10);
                    doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
                }
            });
```

I am getting the following error

```
jspdf.min.js:143 Uncaught (in promise) Proxy must be used when rendering url
```

i have tried setting proxy as http://localhost:8080, it didn't work..

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
var doc = document.getElementById('name');
```

Because the first argument needs to be an element, not an HTML string;